# Set environment variable for chromedriver in Robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I cannot set chromedriver as an environment variable in my Robot framework. It keeps throwing error: chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH.I have shown the screenshot for the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JRUW.png)using intellij.

Comment: I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful; [explanation](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: In Java:   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", thisDriver.getAbsolutePath());    So the environment var name is "webdriver.chrome.driver"... value is path to driver.  From your screenshot there, looks like you forgot to include the extension... should be chromedriver.exe?  You might also have the wrong slashes... forward instead of back... "/", "\"

Comment: @pcalkins I have included the extension its stuck with the same error. Thank you for looking into it though.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using Python + Pycharm Editor + Robot Framework

We will need to save chromedriver.exe in the location C:\Users\befor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

and then we will need to set the environment variable, variable name - PATH and variable value - C:\Users\befor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

and we can use the selenium library keyword as follows , (without creating a webdriver)

Open Browser       https://salesforce.com      browser=chrome